# Transfer binary data from .net core web api to typescript application

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core-2.0, binary-data

I have .net core 3.0 web api application and angular 8 client. So far I manage to transfer some data between them using json serialization. But I wonder how to transfer bytes array from api to client.

I found out that modern fashionable way to send binary is using IActionResult rather than HttpResponseMessage. So in my controller I have such code

```
       [HttpGet("Get-octetstream/{id}")]
       public async Task<FileResult> GetAsOctetStream(int id)
       {
           var bytes= await GetData(id);
           var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
           return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", $"{id}.bin");
       }
```

It works fine, so if I make correspondent request directly in browser I get my data saved in file at once. And data is correct.

But when I'm trying to request this data from angular application:

```
    async getOctetStreamFromServer(id: number) {
    const url =
      Utils.GetWebApiUrl() + `/misc/Get-octetstream/${id}`;
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.currentUser);

    const myHttpOptions = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + currentUser.jsonWebToken,
        ResponseType: "blob",
      },
    };

    const response = await this.httpClient.get(url, myHttpOptions).toPromise();
    return response;
  }
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":
{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":200,"statusText":"OK","url":"http://localhost:11080/misc/
Get-octetstream/16588","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure during 
parsing for http://localhost:11080/misc/Get-vxsor-octetstream/16588","error":{"error":
{},"text":"\u0011\u0...
```

So, could somebody provide some piece of typescript code to fetch binary data from .net core web api service?

Comment: My guess is that you need to set the response type, or `Content-Type`, to `application/octet-stream`

Comment: @Automatico, well it was my first choise, than I've read about blob. But anyway, neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your options:

```
const myHttpOptions = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + currentUser.jsonWebToken,
    },
    responseType: 'blob'
};
```

Comment: Yes! It was my fault. Really ResponseType is not a header. Thank you, very much!